# Processing a file with multithreading in perl

Tags: perl, file-io, concurrency, mapreduce

I am looking for a generic process in PERL similar in concept to a mapreduce in which given an input file in perl, I can have #N (user specified number) different file handles which reads from the different parts of the file.

In other words instead of reading file through one handle I would like to read it from #N different blocks simultaneously. To do this I ideally would prefer not to first divide the files in to #N different sub files. It will be nice if a single file could be read from different locations through non interfering file handles with out any data leak.

The downstream goal is to run #N mapper like jobs on the data read by each file handle and then once everything is done I use a reducer like thing to merge the output of each mapper.

Let me know if this makes sense. It is just a simple thing in my mind to leverage multicores machine we have on the existing per code base with some changes. May be something similar is already out there.

I would appreciate your comments.

Thanks!
-Abhi

Answer (score 7):

The [`seek`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?perlfunc#seek) command can move the cursor of a filehandle to an arbitrary position in a file. If you know the size of the file, you can do something like:

1. Choose N points, evenly spaced throughout the file.
2. Open the N filehandles to the file
3. Have each filehandle `seek` to a different point in the file.
4. On each filehandle, read until you get to the beginning of a line (record, whatever)
5. Process the file until you get to a record after the next point. The [`tell`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?perlfunc#tell) command will tell you your current position while you are processing.